# How can I serve an image with a Perl CGI script?

Tags: perl, image

My Google fu is failing me. How do I use Perl to serve up an already generated image?

Example:

```
<html><body><img src="getimage.pl"></body></html>
```

What goes in getimage.pl?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
my $file = "inner-nav.gif";

## my $length = (stat($file)) [10];
## (stat($file)) [10]; is the inode change time in seconds since  00:00 January 1, 1970 GMT. 
my $length = (stat($file)) [7];
print "Content-type: image/gif\n";
print "Content-length: $length \n\n";
binmode STDOUT;
open (FH,'<', $file) || die "Could not open $file: $!";
my $buffer = "";
while (read(FH, $buffer, 10240)) {
    print $buffer;
}
close(FH);
```

Comment: Sorry - my Perl is extremely rusty.  That was a (tested) example I found on the net.

Comment: Is there something missing? - as my browser indicates it is still in the busy loading state (denoted by animated loading symbol) even after the  image is displayed in the browser. Should there be something added to end of the response sent back to the client, to indicate loading complete?

Answer (score 6):

Something like this ...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;

my $gfx='';
$gfx = makeImage();
print CGI::header( type=>'image/png',
                   expires=>'+1m',
                   content_length=>length($gfx)});
print $gfx;
```

Comment: This assumes n can only handle png images. The query is not that specific, so gotta accommodate for all...

Answer (score 3):

A small correction to the code -- the stat command provided did not return the length of the file.  Some browsers did not care, but others would fail to load the image.  (stat($file))[10] is 'ctime', not the length of the file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
my $file = "inner-nav.gif";
my $length = -s $file;
print "Content-type: image/gif\n";
print "Content-length: $length \n\n";
binmode STDOUT;
open (FH,'<', $file) || die "Could not open $file: $!";
my $buffer = "";
while (read(FH, $buffer, 10240)) {
    print $buffer;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[WWW FAQs: "How do I output images from a Perl/CGI or PHP script"](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/emitimage.html) should get you going in the right direction. You will have to forgive me for not answering your question directly as I haven't touched Perl in about 5 years.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that handles png or jpg files. Lookup the latest version of GD if you want to do more filetypes.

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=18565

#

```
sub serveImage
{
    use GD;

    my ( $localPath ) = @_;

    if( $localPath =~ /\.png/i )
    {
        print "Content-type: image/png\n\n";
        binmode STDOUT;
        my $image = GD::Image->newFromPng( $localPath );
        print $image->png;
    }
    else
    {
        print "Content-type: image/jpeg\n\n";
        binmode STDOUT;
        my $image = GD::Image->newFromJpeg( $localPath );
        print $image->jpeg(100);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

One user asked if there was something missing. I think so. `exit 1;` is missing at the end of the script. Here's my revised version (lol I only added in the `exit 1;`)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
my $file = "inner-nav.gif";
my $length = (stat($file)) [10];
print "Content-type: image/gif\n";
print "Content-length: $length \n\n";
binmode STDOUT;
open (FH,'<', $file) || die "Could not open $file: $!";
my $buffer = "";
while (read(FH, $buffer, 10240)) {
    print $buffer;
}
close(FH);
exit 1;
```

A better way, I think anyway, is to do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# must haves!
use strict;
use warnings;

use CGI;
my $cgi = new CGI; # used in 'getParam($)' for getting URL paramaters

use lib "pm"; # my own perl modules library
use user; # my user related functions
use dir; # my directory handling functions

# these will be used for $fn if $fn not found, read error, or no user
my $file_not_found = "/img_srvr/error-file-not-found.jpg";
my $read_error = "/img_srvr/error-reading-image.jpg";
my $no_such_user = "/img_srvr/error-no-such-user.jpg";

# the premise of the following is to capture all input into separate vars
# verify that each element is correct, and then spit out the image.

 # for my site.  remove it if you like.  see below for getParam($) definition
my $uid = getParam("uid");
if (not userExists($uid)) { printImage($no_such_user); exit 1; }

my $folder = "/img_srvr/$uid"; # the folder where the images are stored

my $fn = getParam("img"); # see below for definition
my $path = "$folder/$fn"; # this, too, _is_ better

if (not fileExists($path))
  { printImage($file_not_found); exit 1; } else
  { printImage($path); }

exit 1;


#########################################################################


######################
sub printImage($) {
  # be sure to do your error checking BEFORE calling this. it'll just
  # blindly rip along.
  my $fn = $_[0];
  my $type = getType($fn); # see sub below
  my $buffer = "";

  print "content-type: image/$type\n"; # these are awful, but ok for now
  print "\n"; # separate just in case we want to add more to the header.

  binmode STDOUT;

  open my $FH, "<", $fn or die "$!";
  while (read ($FH, $buffer, 10240)) {
    print $buffer; # prefer NOT to print as I read...
  }
  close $FH;

  # return $OUTPUT; # this would be better, no?
}

######################
# there's gotta be a better way, spock!
sub getType($) {
  my $f = $_[0];

  if ($f =~ /\.gif$/i) { return "gif"; }
  if ($f =~ /\.jpg|\.jpeg$/i) { return "jpeg"; }
  if ($f =~ /\.png$/i) { return "png"; }

  return "bmp";
}

sub getParam($) {
  return $cgi->param($_[0]);
}
```

Oh! And this might be [a useful link](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html) (mime types!):

====

Finally, using the above `printImage` function I made, is it possible to 'resize' the image? If so, how? I do not want to install another package, or anything like that. It has to be simple.