# Why do my images get clipped when served by this Perl CGI script?

Tags: perl, cgi, jpeg

When I try to print an image to `STDOUT` in a Perl CGI script, the image gets clipped when viewed in the browser.

Here is the following code:

```
if ($path =~ m/\.jpe?g$/i)
{    
  my $length = (stat($path))[7];
  $| = 1;
  print "Content-type: image/jpg\r\n";
  print "Content-length: $length\r\n\r\n";
  open(IMAGE,"<$path");
  binmode(IMAGE);
  binmode(STDOUT);
  my ($image, $buff);
  read IMAGE, $buff, $length;
  syswrite STDOUT, $buff, $length;
  close IMAGE;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `$length` contains the correct value?

Comment: Ensure that the image you expect to see is the right one. Is the file itself corrupted?

Comment: The files are not corrupted, as I can view them entirely in windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI: I have come to the conclusion that the images are in fact corrupt, though they are fully viewable in Windows File Explorer.

The FireFox browser shows the Images clipped(no matter how they are accessed, so I guess this is no longer a Perl problem), but the Safari Browser displays them completely.

The images were re sampled from using Java's imageIO in "jpg" mode. I just changed the mode to "png", and now the newly generated images are showing perfectly in all browsers. So this was actually a Java imageIO issue.

It is solved.

Thank you everyone for your responses.

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to read the entire file into memory before serving, use [File::Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/File::Slurp):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

use CGI::Simple;
use File::Slurp;
use File::stat;

local $| = 1;

my $cgi = CGI::Simple->new;

my $st = stat($path) or die "Cannot stat '$path'";

print $cgi->header(
    -type => 'image/jpeg',
    -length => $st->size,
);

write_file(\*STDOUT, {binmode => ':raw'}, 
    \ read_file( $path, binmode => ':raw' )
);
```

However, reading the entire file will consume large amounts of memory for large images. Therefore, see [How can I serve an image with a Perl CGI script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815670/how-can-i-serve-an-image-with-a-perl-cgi-script/815725#815725).

Comment: if he calls `read` with the `$length` of the image, isn't it read in just one call?

Comment: i read the doc. and i do see a need for returning the number of characters actually read: when reading at the end of the file. example: a file of 240 byte, with `$length` 100: first read returns 100, second read 100, third/last read 40. however, when `$length` is the size of the file, `read` should read the whole file or return an error, but not something in between. shouldn't it?

Comment: @ax You are correct. Thank you. Cleaning up my post and comments. The OP still needs to check the return value of `read` and `syswrite`, though.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: as the `stat` doesn't seem to be problem, some more ideas:

try using unbuffered instead of buffered reading, ie. use [`sysread`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysread.html) instead of [`read`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/read.html). or the other way round: use both buffered `read` and `write`. also, try commenting out the [`$|`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#HANDLE-%3Eautoflush%28EXPR%29). see [*Suffering from Buffering?*](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html) for details on perl buffered io. see also [*How can I serve an image with a Perl CGI script?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815670/how-can-i-serve-an-image-with-a-perl-cgi-script/815725#815725) here on SO for an apparently working solution. **EDIT END**

you are using the wrong [`stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) field. `(stat($path))[10]` is *ctime: inode change time in seconds since the epoch*. it should be `(stat($path))[7]`, *size: total size of file, in bytes*.

Comment: It does not matter if I include content-length or not. I changed the stat as you suggested, but still the image gets cut off

Comment: i just tried your (updated) code here: it is working. so i guess it is something with your image. mind to share a link?

Comment: could it be a server/installation issue?

Comment: maybe. but i think it's more probable that it has to do with perl's buffered io. see my **EDIT** above.